# issue with mysql join table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with three tables:

1. list of users
2. list of items
3. list of tasks table to say which users will do which task (join table)

Each day the list of tasks will change. So I will manually change this task list in phpmyadmin. What I want is for every task to be assigned to every user. I can see that this is manually possible in phpmyadmin but it would not really be feasible to do this manually for more than a few users.

I am really struggling to see what I have done wrong in my code. I'm really new to php. When I post the correct url with postman (I am doing an api using slim) it says there were no errors but when I check my mysql database the user task table is still empty.

Here is the code in my index.php:

```
$app->post('/tasks', function() use ($app) {

        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        $response = array();

        if (isset($headers['Authorization'])){

        $db = new DbHandler();
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];

            if ($api_key == '12345'){
                    $task_id = $db->createUserTask();

            }else{
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["message"] = "Invalid Api key";
                    echoRespnse(400, $response);
                    $app->stop();
            }

       }else{

            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid Api Key";
            echoRespnse(400, $response);
            $app->stop();
  }                
    });
```

Here is the code for my createUserTask function with is part of DbHandler:

```
    public function createUserTask() {

    $no_users = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX (id) FROM users");
    $no_tasks = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX (id) FROM tasks");

    if ($no_users >= 0 && $no_tasks >=0){
            for($i = 1; $i == $no_users; $i++){
                    for ($u = 1; $u == $no_tasks; $u++){
                            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_tasks(user_id, task_id) values(i, u)");
                            $result = $stmt->execute();

                            if (false === $result) {
                                    die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                            }
                            $stmt->close();
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Can you see what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the 3 following lines:

```
$no_users = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX (id) FROM users");
$no_tasks = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX (id) FROM tasks");
if ($no_users >= 0 && $no_tasks >=0){
```

The prepare() prepares the statements for execution, but does not execute it, so the if() will always evaluate to false. You have to execute() these statements and read the returned values from them.

However, you can do the whole thing in a single sql statement:

```
insert into user_tasks(user_id, task_id)
select users.id, tasks.id from users, tasks
```

No need for complicated nested loops. The select part of the insert produces a carthesian join of user and task ids.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. When I try the sql I get 500 internal error and the error is unexpected into. Do you mean to remove all the code from $no_users to the end of the if statement in createUserTask? Does that sql also assign each task to each users or just for one? Thanks again

Comment: Without seeing what you have exactly tried, it's difficult to tell what may have gone wrong. The sugested sql statement pretty much takes care of the entire createUserTask() function. Execute just the select part of it in phpmyadmin and you will understand what it is doing.

Comment: I was running that in my code. Just tried it in phpmyadmin and it worked perfectly. I also think this approach is much more secure than what I was trying to do before. Thank you so much. :)